# Animation while changing orientation

Tags: android

Is it possible to set `animation` when we move from an activity in landscape view to an activity in portrait view ?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible, but not trivial. Add this property to your `<activity>` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
```

Then, override your activity's [`onConfigurationChanged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) and perform the animation there.

Comment: I gave overridePendingTransition(R.anim.login_fadein, R.anim.splash_fadeout);But is not working.

Comment: Make sure it'll hidden the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you an idea. Try to implement it this way.

1. Add viewFlipper as a parent node in your layout and set animation to flipper.
2. Now when you change configuration from portrait to lndscape or vice-versa, you get a call to the method onConfigurationChanged() in your activity. (you will have to overide this method).
3. Now animate your flipper using startFlipping() and you are done.

Thanks.