# Animation while changing orientation

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Animation while changing orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544134/animation-while-changing-orientation)

Is it possible to set animation between two activities in landscape and portrait view respectively android.